# What vendor supports the trill protocol?

Tags: cisco, router, switch, ethernet

I would like to know what manufacturers support trill and on what platforms specific.

I am especially interested in Cisco platforms.

I can't find to much information on the internet about it other than the fact that nexus series are capable of running trill.

Comment: This seems like a question that we could convert to a community wiki with one answer where we list the platforms supporting trill.  Are you willing to consider trill-like technologies, such as Cisco's FabricPath?

Comment: No ... I am interested in standard trill

Comment: google.com site:arista.com pulls up a couple of maybe's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brocade with their VDX line of ethernet switching gear uses it.  But the thing to keep in mind is that different vendors implement TRILL in different ways and they don't necessarily interoperate. The standard is so loose that two vendor versions can claim to be standards compliant but be completely incompatible.